# How to set values to array pointers

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I am trying to set a value to array pointers and also set the pointers to NULL but when I try to run the program I am getting `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` and I believe it is because of what I have in the for loop. Please help

```
struct node {

int value;

node *next;

};
int main(){

node **adj;
int vert;
cout<<"Please enter the number of vertices: ";
cin>>vert;
adj = new node* [vert-1];

for (int x = 0; x <= vert-1; x++)//set all the names of the value.
{
    adj[x]->value = x;
    cout<< adj[x]->value;
    adj[x] = NULL
} 

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have to also do `adj[x] = new node;` within your loop. Also, `cout<< adj[1]->name;`, did you mean `cout<< adj[x]->name;`

Comment: name is what i use to have it but I switched it to value and forgot to name.

Comment: @JackWhitham please try posting it as an answer and not a comment if you believe it addresses the question

Comment: And please do not correct mistakes in the code when you were asking to find them. Once you correct them in your question answers/comments that helped to find them are rather confusing when one does not know the history

Answer (score 0):

Using `adj = new node* [vert-1];` just reserve memory for `vert-1` pointers but, but you are assigning values to each of these pointers without reserving memory for them.

The correct way of doing what you want is:

```
node * adj;
..
adj = new node[vert-1]; // reserv memory for all information

// EDITED for out of array bounds: thanks @Leiaz
for (int x = 0; x < vert-1; x++)//set all the names of the value.
{
    // now, you can modify a reserved memory portion
    adj[x].value = x;
    adj[x].next = NULL;
}
```

Comment: what's the difference with `->` and `.` ?

Comment: `adj[x]`is a node, not a pointer to node. Accessing to a struct item is using `.`. Accessing to a item belonging to struct pointer is made using `->`. Read a little bit more about C/C++ pointers.